# Where does Oreo show channel description?

Tags: android

Since Android O, it requires us to setup `NotificationChannel`

In `NotificationChannel`, one of the APIs is

```
notificationChannel.setDescription
```

However, when I went into notification settings in Android O, I can't find anything related to description.

[image]

May I know, where does Android O show notification description information?

---

I scroll till end of **Nofication category**, but can only see a clickable "Additional settings in the app"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Descriptions shows at the end of channel details

[image: Notification channel details]

Comment: Do you have idea why it is not showing in device running API 27?